# Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt after deploying on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-deployment

my web app is working fine on localhost, but when I publish it on Azure, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

On a localhost is working fine.

I am using 4.5 framework, and it is definned in web.config file too. I tried to reinstall it in nuget manager but I get

> Package 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.4.0.2.206221351' already exists in
>   project 'project1'

I also can't find this assembly in references folder.
This is the first time I have expirienced this type of a problem.

What do you recommend me to do?

Regards,
Sandi

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have figured it out. I updated System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt reference via nuget package manager and it works again.

Regards!

Comment: I have this reference via nuget package, and I am getting a simliar, but different error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: in my case i have installed to web project

Answer (score 37):

There is a known issue in Azure Functions host: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5894

The current workaround is to add the following to your .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: In this way, I can fix the issue related to "Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt' after deploying on Azure".

But I met another issue:
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: EnsureClientNotePageThumbnail. System.Security.Principal.Windows: Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform.

Answer (score 1):

it is easy to resolve. just go to the web config and find the package in which you are getting the error. and check the version mentioned in the web.config. and compare it to the NuGet package from the reference which is already installed in the project. and make it similar in both.

[Nuget Package version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NaBX.png)

In my case, I have installed the 3.10.10.0 and in web config, it shows me different. I have changed it to 3.10.10.0. and everything works fine.

[web.config version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkh0K.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by selecting 'Refresh dependencies' of the Detected Dependencies in my Install Project. I think its a bug, as the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt assembly resided in the program files target folder, and had a compliant versioning.
If you're not working with VS, perhaps you could can relate this to your own development environment.

Answer (score -1):

I had to roll back the dot net framework to 4.5.1